# Run time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting this error:

> Run time error '1004':Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

After I changed this code to:

```
iColumn = Application.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0)
```

It was:

```
iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0)
```

Now I have this error on this code:

```
shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
```

```
Sub SearchData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim shDatabase As Worksheet ' Database sheet
    Dim shSearchData As Worksheet 'SearchData sheet

    Dim iColumn As Variant 'To hold the selected column number in Database sheet
    Dim iDatabaseRow As Long 'To store the last non-blank row number available in Database sheet
    Dim iSearchRow As Long 'To hold the last non-blank row number available in SearachData sheet

    Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
    Dim sValue As String 'To hold the search text value


    Set shDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")


    iDatabaseRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    sColumn = frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value

    sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value


    iColumn = Application.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:U1"), 0)


    'Remove filter from Database worksheet

    If shDatabase.FilterMode = True Then

        shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False

    End If

    'Apply filter on Database worksheet

    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Project Number" Then

        shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue

    Else

        shDatabase.Range("A1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"

    End If

    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Customer" Then

        shDatabase.Range("B1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue

    Else

        shDatabase.Range("B1:U" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"

    End If

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shDatabase.Range("B:B")) >= 2 Then

        'Code to remove the previous data from SearchData worksheet

        shSearchData.Cells.Clear

        shDatabase.AutoFilter.Range.Copy shSearchData.Range("A1")

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 21

        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "25, 70, 50, 50, 70, 50, 30, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 90, 50, 90"

        If iSearchRow > 1 Then

            frmForm.lstDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!A2:T" & iSearchRow

            MsgBox "Records found."

        End If


    Else

       MsgBox "No record found."

    End If

    shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to test whether `iColumn` is an error or not before trying to use it in a range. `If Not IsError(iColumn) Then`.  When the match is not found it will return an error.  you must account for this.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner could you please put it in the full script?